# Parameter for Action

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have Code Like this

```
  func showSearchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, navigationItem: UINavigationItem) {
    searchBar.alpha = 0
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(nil, animated: true)

    for subView in searchBar.subviews  {
        for subsubView in subView.subviews  {
            if let textField = subsubView as? UITextField {
                textField.attributedPlaceholder =  NSAttributedString(string:NSLocalizedString("Search", comment:""),
                    attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 25/255, green: 128/255, blue: 214/255, alpha: 1)])
                textField.font = UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-Medium", size: 15)
                textField.textColor = UIColor(red: 65/255, green: 65/255, blue: 65/255, alpha: 1)
            }
        }
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        searchBar.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { finished in
            searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    })

}

    func hideSearchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, navigationItem: UINavigationItem, navigationController: UINavigationController, leftButton: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Search, target: self, action: "showSearchBar:")
    searchBar.alpha = 0
    navigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = button
    navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(leftButton, animated: true)
    searchBar.clipsToBounds = true
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { finished in

    })
}
```

I've error after func hideSearchBar called
I don't know but i think error because I call showSearchBar in hideSearchBar but on showSearchBar have 2 parameters but i not send it... how can I send 2 parameters on action

I have try

```
showSearchBar:
showSearchBar::
```

but it still error, what should i do?
or i have another error on my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the name right, you need to translate from a Swift method declaration to the Objective-C name of that method. This translation is simple and follows rules that are completely mechanical, but you will be entering the name as a literal string and it is all too easy to make a typing mistake, so be careful:

1. The name starts with everything that precedes the left parenthesis in the method name.
2. If the method takes no parameters, stop. That’s the end of the name.
3. If the method takes any parameters, add a colon.
4. If the method takes more than one parameter, add the external names of all parameters except the first parameter, with a colon after each external parameter name.

Observe that this means that if the method takes any parameters, its Objective-C name will end with a colon. Capitalization counts, and the name should contain no spaces or other punctuation except for the colons.

To illustrate, here are three Swift method declarations, with their Objective-C names given as a string in a comment:

```
func sayHello() -> String // "sayHello"

func say(s:String) // "say:"

func say(s:String, times n:Int) // "say:times:"
```

It is possible to crash even though your selector name corresponds correctly to a declared method. For example, here’s a small test `class` that creates an `NSTimer` and tells it to call a certain method once per second:

```
class MyClass {
    var timer : NSTimer? = nil
    func startTimer() {
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1,
            target: self, selector: "timerFired:",
            userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    func timerFired(t:NSTimer) {
        println("timer fired")
    }
}
```

There’s nothing wrong with that `class` structurally; it compiles, and can be instantiated when the app runs. But when we call `startTimer`, we crash. The problem is not that `timerFired` doesn’t exist, or that `"timerFired:"` is not its name; the problem is that Cocoa can’t find `timerFired`. This, in turn, is because our class `MyClass` is a pure Swift class; therefore it lacks the Objective-C introspection and message-sending machinery that would permit Cocoa to see and call `timerFired`. Any one of the following solutions will solve the problem:

- Declare `MyClass` as a subclass of `NSObject`.
- Declare `MyClass` with the `@objc` attribute.
- Declare `timerFired` with the `@obc` attribute.
- Declare `timerFired` with the `dynamic` keyword. (But this would be overkill; you should reserve use of `dynamic` for situations where it is needed, namely where Objective-C needs the ability to alter the implementation of a class member.)

Here is [Documentation](http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_selectors).

In your case do this way:

```
"showSearchBar:navigationItem:"
```

**UPDATE:**

Remove General.swift from your project and replace your code in Home.swift with this code:

```
@IBAction func searchBarAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    showSearchBar(self.searchBar, navItem: self.navigationItem)

}

func showSearchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, navItem navigationItem: UINavigationItem) {
    searchBar.alpha = 0
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(nil, animated: true)

    for subView in searchBar.subviews  {
        for subsubView in subView.subviews  {
            if let textField = subsubView as? UITextField {
                textField.attributedPlaceholder =  NSAttributedString(string:NSLocalizedString("Search", comment:""),
                    attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 25/255, green: 128/255, blue: 214/255, alpha: 1)])
                textField.font = UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-Medium", size: 15)
                textField.textColor = UIColor(red: 65/255, green: 65/255, blue: 65/255, alpha: 1)
            }
        }
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        searchBar.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { finished in
            searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()

    })
}

//MARK: UISearchBarDelegate
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    hideSearchBar(self.searchBar, navigationItem: self.navigationItem, navigationController: self.navigationController!, leftButton: btnMenu)
}

func hideSearchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, navigationItem: UINavigationItem, navigationController: UINavigationController, leftButton: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Search, target: self, action: "searchBarAction:")  //add your button action here.

    searchBar.alpha = 0
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
    navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(leftButton, animated: true)
    searchBar.clipsToBounds = true
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { finished in

    })
}
```

Comment: I've try "showSearchBar:navigationItem:" but it still error, i dont know maybe parameters on this func required... can i send it? but thanks for ur respond..